# Multimode Search in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

The code is listed below , is my code for **multimode** search in **ado.net** , i use now **entity framework** and i dont know how write this perfectly with **less code**

```
string query = '"SELECT id From user";
if(filter1 != "" || filter2 != "")
{
    query += "where ";
}

if(filter1 != "")
{
    query += "name='" + filter1 + "'";
    if(filter2 != "")
        query += " and "
}

if(filter2 != "")
   query += "name" + filter2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample:

```
YourIQueryableResults.Where(x => filter1!="" && (x.Name == filter1))
```

or

```
if (filter1!="") { YourIQueryableResults = YourIQueryableResults.Where(x => x.Name == filter1)}
```

Comment: I think, you oversaw the last two lines, that have to be added aswell to your condition, didnt you? You might edit it and add the condition using the ||-operator :)

Comment: @Jannik this is just a sample for usage of IQueryables.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var result = (from s in db.user
            select s).AsQueryable();

if (filter1 != "")
{
    result = result.Where(x=>x.name == filter1);
}

if (filter2 != "")
{
    result = result.Where(x=>x.name == filter2);
}

var output = result.ToList();
```